# Who is the server and who is the client in UDP?

Tags: networking, udp

In TCP, you can differentiate between servers and clients, because servers are those who bind and accept (TCP listeners) and clients just connect to those servers. Both can send and receive.

But, in UDP how do you differentiate between servers and clients? There is no special behavior to differentiate between servers or clients in UDP, right? It seems that we can only classify machines involved in a UDP connection as senders and receivers. A server could be either, or both. It can receive data from many clients or it can send data to many clients (e.g. multicast server).

Please correct me if I am wrong and point me to the correct forum if I posted the question in the wrong one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a server or a client with UDP. There are just peers.

Comment: That's not true of UDP any more than it is of TCP.

Comment: @RussellBorogove As I didn't say it was true of TCP, and as it *is* true of UDP, your comment is 100% incorrect. The thing that makes TCP a client/server protocol is the socket in LISTENING state that accepts connections. That structure does not exist in UDP.

Comment: DNS, TFTP, and many games have protocols on top of UDP which are clearly client-server. To the extent your answer is accurate, it's irrelevant. If a host is calling recv() on a UDP socket bound to a well-known port, it's acting as a server.

Comment: @RussellBorogove That makes those applications client-server. It doesn't make UDP client-server. I can't make head or tail of your final sentence. If my answer is accurate it must be relevant as it answers the question.

Comment: Re. my final sentence. A machine that tries to receive UDP packets on port 53 is a DNS server. The fact that there's no persistent connection formed does not invalidate the fact that there's a clear client (the machine that calls send()) and server (the machine that calls recv()). At this point I think you and I have an irreconcilable semantic disagreement, though.

Comment: Also, I note that RFC 793, which defines the TCP protocol, does not use the words "client" or "server" to describe the ends of the connection. Apart from one example, the words don't even appear in the document.

Comment: @RussellBorogove What about when that DNS server contacts another DNS server, using the same socket? Did it suddenly become a client? What about a multicast client: they listen on well-known ports: are they servers too? Your definition is too imprecise to be useful.

Comment: Did it suddenly become a client? You could say so loosely, yeah. The point I'm trying to make is that "client" and "server" are most often role-based terms that aren't dependent on the underlying communication technology. Consider something like SETI At Home or Folding At Home - is the listening end a "server of work requests" or is the calling end a "server of computation"?

Comment: @RussellBorogove So you are now agreeing with my comment above that it is the "applications [that are] client-server", not the protocol.

Comment: @RussellBorogove It isn't me who is being sloppy or unhelpful here.

Answer (score 1):

Think about UDP as a Sender -> Receiver communication instead of Client <=> Server.

Since UDP is a connectionless protocol a response from the Receiver may or may not happen. That (among other things) is why TCP is considered more reliable but slower than UDP.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectionless_protocol

http://www.diffen.com/difference/TCP_vs_UDP

Answer (score -1):

Not an expert with networking, but this is my understanding.

TCP and UDP are network protocols i.e. dealing with how data is to be transferred between nodes. If you were to look at the packet structure for both TCP and UDP, you will find that both have a source node section and a destination node section. Moreover, a physical machine will still exist as the source of information even in UDP. Whether, you call it server or just a client is a decision which the architecture of the system shall decide.

So, I think you are referring to a level above transmission of data i.e. in my understanding an architecture of network application. That is when we talk about client server applications, and may be P2P kind of an architecture where there can be multiple physical machines providing data. So, the terminology depends on which context are you referring.

To answer your question, yes a server and client can exist in both TCP and UDP. Let the architects decide!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Upto the community or the author of this question to decide :)

Comment: A TCP application with a listening socket is already a server. Nothing to do with any decision by the application designer. It's built into the protocol.